# Bold or italic text in Toast without creation View?

Tags: android, text, toast

**Summary**

I want to create a Toast ***without creation View*** as content for Toast with bold text inside in Toast.

**Question**

Is it possible?

**Update**

How to create this effect?

Answer (score 17):

try something like this,...

`Html.fromHtml()` this causes the html styling to modify our text

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Html.fromHtml("<big><b>exciting</b></big><small><i>and cool</i></small>text<br>"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this helps...